# .Net Web Service Memory Pressure Error

Tags: c#, web-services, memory-management, assemblies, clr

I have a web service I'm trying to use on one of my sites. When I call the web service (which is created in C#) I get an error on several lines where try to execute an SP, which was created as an assembly. This web service works on our development environment but not on live. Our live and dev environments run on the same server, but different databases.

The error is:

Sql Exception: Failed to initialize the Common Language Runtime (CLR) v2.0.50727 due to memory pressure. Please restart SQL server in Address Windowing Extensions (AWE) mode to use CLR integration features.

CLR is enabled on both live and dev. No temp tables are used. I believe its already in AWE mode. WSE was installed on the server and I'm using .Net 2.0

The SP I'm trying to call in the web service takes a string as an argument and returns a byte[].

Is there a size limitation on web services?

Any suggestions?

Edit: We're using MSSQL 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boss man had to increase the amount of ram available to the system as most of it was dedicated to sql server. This cleared up the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the process is working on your dev server I'd have to say that it's not a limitation of the system as it's clearly demonstrated working.

I'm afraid it's probably a case of crawling over both systems (IIS & SQL Server) on each box comparing configurations. I think the error message you are getting is indicating that AWE mode isn't enabled on the production box, so that would be the first thing to check.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This error isn't related to the web service, it's an error from Sql Server.  Do you see that same error if you try to run the SP in Sql Management Studio?